# Can't figure out how to work with jQuery form and .length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on a project which involves authenticating form fields based on the length of the strings in the fields.  For example, the zip field needs to be atleast 5 characters.  This is the code I have so far;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Building the Address from the Form
var address = document.getElementById("address");
var city = document.getElementById("city");
var state = document.getElementById("state");
var zip = document.getElementById("zip");

var addressobject = buildAddress(address.value, city.value, state.value, zip.value);

function buildAddress(address, city, state, zip){
    addressobject = {
        address: address,
        city: city,
        state: state,
        zip: zip,
        toString: function(){
            return (this.address + "," + this.city + "," + this.state + "," + this.zip);
        }
    }
    return(addressobject);
}
//Validation Function
$("#btn").on("click", function(addressobject) {
  if(address.zip < 5){
    alert("good");
  } else
    alert("bad");
});
```

});

There are other parts to this project however right now I just need to get this authentication part working.  Again, I can't seem to get the (address.zip < 5) working, instead as of right now any input in the zip field produces an alert box of "bad".   The above document.getElementById is referencing the div input id from the html page.  Should I be referencing something else instead maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Note that any text input is a string and cannot be evaluated  as a number. You either need to convert it to a number via parseInt (or parseFloat) and compare it against a five digit number that is the minimum NUMBER that you want to validate or get the length of the inputted string from the text input and compare that against the 5 characters you require using the .length property.

Comment: I don't exactly need it to recognize the number as an integer, just need to recognize it and know the length.

Comment: .length() is your friend! Incidentally - to make a more fluid UI why don't you call the validate length function on the blur of the zip field? or even on the keyup event. This would prevent the user getting to the end of the form and then realising that they have to go back to a previously filled in field.

Comment: That's what i had thought orginally, but now this is proving to be more complicated than it should be.  adding .length() only takes away any alert boxes that were showing up.

Comment: length is not a function it is a property